# Reduce MNIST dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, jupyter, mnist, metadata

I am working on the MNIST dataset. How I can reduce 50% of this data?

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: What do you mean? Compress each image into $\dfrac{28\times 28}{2}=392$ features/pixels? Use $30000$ training images rather than the usual $60000?$ Use $5000$ testing images rather than the usual $10000?$ Some combination of these? Something totally different?

Comment: I want to use the total dataset as 35000

Comment: What prevents you from just taking $35000$ images? // That’s still a decent number of images, and your training on that still won’t be immediate like a small OLS regression. Why shrink down to $35000?$